# React Componenet not being rendered

Tags: javascript, next.js, frontend

My component is beign rendered Blank at the end
Everything is fine with the api call, and i add some console.log() for debug, can anybody give me a light ?

Basically, i want to retrieve data from an api that has this json structure

```
[
    {
        "trackName": "Beira de Piscina (Remix)",
        "trackUri": "spotify:track:6a0kQTjyGmfwBF0tLVgEha",
        "artistImage": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27366127aa6c868a01e97f62d64"
    },
    {
        "trackName": "Beira de Piscina",
        "trackUri": "spotify:track:25XUxLporfgzl2rf2mtgmj",
        "artistImage": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b2738e2cc04d7c1ed2beb3216ff2"
    }
]
```

And i want to render those on a page, its an example code, but i don't understand why i'm getting a blank page :(

That's my code:

```
import {useState} from "react";

export default function SearchTracks() {

    const [formSuccess, setFormSuccess] = useState(false)
    const [trackList, setTracklist] = useState()

    const handleSubmit = async (event: any) => {
        event.preventDefault()

        const data = {
            trackName: event.target.trackName.value
        }

        const endpoint = `http://myEndPoint:8080/tracks?trackName=${data.trackName}`
        const options = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'access-token': 'MyAccessToken'
            }
        }
        const response = await fetch(endpoint, options)

        const result = await response.json()
        setFormSuccess(true)

        setTracklist(result)
    };

    const renderTrack = (trackListResponse) : any => {
        const myMap = new Map(Object.entries(trackListResponse))
        return myMap.forEach((trackValue) => {
            return trackValue.map(track => {
                let value = buildTrackContainer(track)
                console.log(value)
                return value
            })
        })
    }

    const buildTrackContainer = (track) => {
       console.log("Building track: " + track.trackName)
       return <li key={track.trackUri}>
            <p>{track.trackName}</p>
            <p>{track.trackUri}</p>
            <img src={track.artistImage}/>
        </li>
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {formSuccess ?
                <ul>
                    { renderTrack({trackList}) }
                </ul>
                :
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <label htmlFor="trackName">Track Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="trackName" name="trackName" required/>
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

In console i can see that my react element is returned in function

[My Console Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRpiT.png)

[Result Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WQPu.png)

Comment: Pro tip: having renderXXX functions inside a component body (or buildTrackContainer) has got to be (one of the) the biggest anti-pattern in react. Take these functions outside your component, and have your parent component  render them as new components with the appropriate props. Your future self will thank you for the readability

Comment: @Adam Thank you, yeah, it's really a V0, i'm a full back-end guy, who know's really really "nothing" of react,  but that's the next step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resides in your `renderTrack()` function. Try this out:

```
    const renderTrack = (trackListResponse) : any => {
        return trackListResponse.trackList.map(track =>
            buildTrackContainer(track)
        );
    };
```

The problem is that `forEach` doesn't actually return anything, so all it's getting is `undefined`. An alternative approach would be to create an empty array, this push elements into the empty array within the `forEach` call, but this feel like its probably more trouble than it's worth. For example:

```
    const renderTrack = (trackListResponse) : any => {
        const myMap = new Map(Object.entries(trackListResponse));
        const renderElements = [];
        myMap.forEach(trackValue => {
            return trackValue.map(track => {
                let value = buildTrackContainer(track);
                renderElements.push(value);
            });
        });
        return renderElements;
    };
```